# How update data in constructor in form

Tags: zend-framework

I have form in Zend and on constructor i set some data:

```
class FormAbc {
    public function __construct($parParams = null){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->addElement('text','name_field1',array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'for test: '.$parParams['content'],
        ));
    }
}
```

In my Controller i send to constructor some data

```
$varParams = array(
    'content' => 'hello world',
);

$objFormAbc = new FormAbc($varParams);
```

Now in my view i see this Hello World. But when i do some with after run new FormAbc i would like change this data 'content' how can i do it ? i need for example:

```
$varParams = array(
    'content' => 'hello world',
);

$objFormAbc = new FormAbc($varParams);

change my content to 'World Hello' before send to view

$this->view->forms = array(
    'formabc' => $objFormAbc,
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the element and update the label:

```
$objFormAbc->getElement('name_field1')->setLabel('World Hello');
```